# Contador al inciar una pagina HTML

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Estoy realizando una practica de `html`, y se me pide que cuando pasen 5 segundo se cambia una linea de texto a color rojo y el texto se cambie a "ha cambiado!".

El código `html` es el siguiente:

```
<div class="cincoseg" v-bind:style="styleObject: pasaron5s" >
            <li>El color de esta linea debe cambiar a rojo despues de 5 segundos, y debe cambiar este texto a:"Ha cambiado!"</li>
            </div>
```

El `js` es el siguiente respecto a este fragmento:

```
 mounted() {
      setTimeout(actualiza,5000);
    },

methods: {
      actualiza: function(){
        console.log("el valor es"+app.pasaron5s);
        app.pasaron5s = true;
        console.log("el valor es"+app.pasaron5s);
        var boton = document.getElementById("cincoseg");
        boton.innerHTML = "Ha cambiado!";
      },

con las variables:

     data: {
          pasaron5s:false,
          styleObject: {
            font_color: 'red',
          },
    }
```

Como podéis ver, tengo un par de `console log` y no se muestran por lo que esa función no se llega a ejecutar. No tengo ni idea de que puede ser ya que soy principiante en `HTML`, si alguien me pudiese echar una mano.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: porque esa funcion esta en el created y no en el mounted? y aparte, porque si estas usando vue buscas un elemento en lugar de pasarle una propiedad?

Comment: No se que diferencia hay entre created y mounted, y lo de buscar el elemento ya lo modificare cuando funcione. Gracias

Comment: Entonces lee [aca](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Diagrama-del-Ciclo-de-vida) porque hay una gran diferencia.. en el create no existe nada...

Comment: Una sugerencia, la "clase" empieza en numero, algunas veces, que el nombre de la clase empiece en numero podría dar ciertos errores. No he utilizado Vue.js, por lo que solo te puedo dar esa sujerencia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    pasaron5s:false,
  },
  methods: {
   toggle: function(todo){
     todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      setTimeout(function(){
          this.pasaron5s = true;
          console.log("el valor es"+this.pasaron5s);
          var boton = document.getElementById("5s");
          boton.innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'> Ha cambiado!</span>";
        },5000);
    },
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="5s" >
      <li>El color de esta linea debe cambiar a rojo despues de 5 segundos, y debe cambiar este texto a:"Ha cambiado!"</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Realice estas modificaciones, tienes que ponerlo en el mounted.

https://jsfiddle.net/bardalesj/sgeorxk8/17/ este es el demo